# Border of input thinner than that of a div

Tags: html, css

I currently have this input and div next to each other:

[image: Input box with search button]

As you can see the border of the input is much thinner than the div containing the search icon. Here is the code:

HTML

```css
.location_input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font: normal 16px/normal"Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  margin-left: 6px;
  position: relative;
  top: 42%;
  transform: translateY(-42%);
}

.update_location_wrapper {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  position: relative;
  top: 42%;
  transform: translateY(-42%);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='location_input' placeholder='Enter a location' id='location_input'>
<div class='update_location_wrapper'>
  <div class='update_location_text'>
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/0p5bSIO.png" alt="Search" height="20" width="20">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get the border of the div to match the input border?

Comment: What is the HTML code ?

Comment: Added the HTML code.

Comment: Could you host the `../img/search-icon-black.png` image on a public server, please ?

Comment: Sure do you have a recommendation to which site?

Comment: StackOverflow uses https://imgur.com.

Comment: http://imgur.com/0p5bSIO is a link to the image.

Comment: removed some of your code but while doing so looks like the issue was fixed. Take a look and let me know if thats what you were looking for. http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/LGQMyo

Comment: The transform translateY is making that blurry line.

Comment: try adding a border inside the input as border:<some pixels> inset <color>;

Comment: @sniels you are correct that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As input borders looks somewhat different on different browser, you could add a wrapper with a border, or you can do like this, where you increase the right padding of the input and move the search button inside it.

```css
.location_input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 3px 35px 3px 15px;
  font: normal 16px/normal "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.update_location_wrapper{
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-left: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='location_input' placeholder='Enter a location' id='location_input'>
<div class='update_location_wrapper'>
  <div class='update_location_text'><img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="Search" height="20" width="20"></div>
</div>
```